# Does TurboTax mail my state forms for me?

Tags: united-states, taxes, turbotax, state-taxes, idaho

I just filed with TurboTax, and it mentioned along the filing process that my state taxes (for Idaho) have to be filed by mail, though they didn't show the forms to actually mail in.

Does that mean TurboTax mailed them for me? Or do I need to do my taxes again on paper? It shows that my taxes were filed successfully but I'm skeptical about whether or not the whole process is finished.

Comment: Did you pay money?  E-filing state taxes costs money (30 bucks I think), otherwise you have to do it yourself if you didn't pay.

Comment: _Why_ e-filling state taxes costs money is a mystery, since doing so saves the state a considerable amount of money on paper handling and data entry. As far as I can tell it's entirely to protect the tax software publisher's profits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I didn't use TurboTax this year, but I have in other years.  When I've had to file by mail or chosen to do so, I always had to print and mail myself.  I'd definitely run this down until you're sure, but until you know for sure otherwise, I'd assume that they are not mailing anything for you.  Intuit has a site for questions specific to TurboTax.  You might do better posting there and/or calling customer support.

Answer (score 3):

If you did not pay for electronic submission of the state forms, it is your responsibility to print and mail the state return. This is normally done as one of the final steps of the interview process, of you can tell Ttax to print those forms for you.

Comment: This isn't exactly what he's asking, though; his state doesn't _have_ electronic submission.

Comment: @Joe seems like they do http://tax.idaho.gov/i-1027.cfm?seg=free

Comment: @coburne Well, the question says Turbotax says he can't... It's apparently not an entirely uncommon problem, see for example [this entirely unhelpful response to the same question](https://ttlc.intuit.com/questions/2605156-why-can-t-turbo-tax-efile-my-idaho-tax-return) last year @ TT's online help forum.  Of course the site they direct you to check shows nothing of consequence, so it's likely some problem in TT, but still...

Comment: When I used to use TT, I often encountered "unsupported" cases where it won't let you file electronically. Whether the limitation is on the government side or on the TT side seemed to vary. (This is one of the reasons that I stopped using TT.) @Joe

Comment: @Brick is there an alternative that doesn't involve going to a tax consultant/accountant?

Comment: I have not encountered cases where tax software gives up. Your milage may vary. If you can't file electronically for some reason, print hardcopy and file  by mail.

Comment: @Qix I usually just do taxes on my own. NY state and federal both have pretty simple forms and my taxes aren't too complicated (no taxes, no property, decent income+investment income.. so just a w2 and 1099 div). I usually compare my self-made one with one generated from tax software to double check correctness. I recently filed my girlfriends taxes and HR block used an Earned Income Tax credit that I didn't know about (she made about $5k last year..initially owed $600 in taxes - self employed, wasn't paying any taxes so I expected the number to be big - but the EIC lowered it to about $150),

Comment: @basher, huh, good to know. I might consider it next year then. Thanks!

Comment: @Qix no problemo. had a bit of a typo there with the 'no taxes'. Think I meant no mortage, no property, no real deductions etc(only student loan interest). Federal site has a link to the fillable forms: https://www.irs.gov/uac/Free-File:-Do-Your-Federal-Taxes-for-Free. State one I found via google (following an xxx.ny.gov link). This was my 5th year doing it solo. Perhaps once I buy property I'll consult an account but they're pretty simple if you just rent and are a w2 employee (and always double-check my return via 3rd party software + last years return, just in case).